# Batcher's odd even merge sort parallel strategy

Tags: c, sorting, openmp

I am trying to parallelize batcher's odd even merge sort.
The progress i made so far is this

if there is an array like below
a[8] = {8,6,4,2,1,7,3,5}
I have used **omp parallel for** on two halves of the above array as below

```
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
    for (i = 0; i < halfSize; ++i)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < halfSize; ++j)
        {
            if (a[i] > a[j])
            {
                temp =  a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }   

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
    for (i=halfSize; i < arraySize; ++i)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < arraySize; ++j)
        {
            if (a[i] > a[j])
            {
                temp =  a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

In above halfSize is 4 and arraySize is 8, this basically parallelizes the two halves of the given array, so final result will be as below
a[8] = {2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7}

Now as per Batcher's odd even merge sort algorithm, I have to sort the even position elements and odd position elements of the above sorted array.

To implement that in a parallel way, can I just do a parallel for on the even elements and parallel for on odd elements. Just like two above parallel for loops I have. **I need suggestions, I hope you guys can keep it simple.**

After the above step is done, i have to swap the adjacent elements(except the first element) in the array obtained from above step. I am going to use a final parallel for to do that. Is it preferred to go this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title mentions merge sort, but after looking this up on wiki, Batcher's algorithm is type of hardware oriented sorting network: a series of compare / swap circuits, groups of which can be performed in parallel. The index pattern is more complex than just adjacent even and odd pairs. The wiki diagram shows an example for an array of 8 integers, and the grouping that allows for parallel operations. Note that the example code output of indexes is not in the same order as the diagram.

Near the bottom of the wiki Batcher article is an iterative algorithm used to select the indexes to be used for the compare / swap circuits. I don't know if it would match the diagram for the 8 element case.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batcher_odd%E2%80%93even_mergesort

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network

I'm not sure it's a practical method for a software sort, but it would be a way to test what would end up as a hardware implementation.

Comment: thank you for your time. I already did what you mentioned, I am kinda looking for suggestions if this  is good approach.. I mean I had to use two parallel for loops to work on two halves, can it be a single parallel for loop..? How do you think i can make this as a merge sort instead of bubble sort. Should I split the arrays into two halves and then sort and then later merge them...?

Comment: @codenoob - I updated my answer. Seems this is an extension to sorting networks which use a series of compare / swap circuits or software to implement a sort for reasonably small number of integers.